# Adding a description to GitHub repo

Tags: github, permissions

My boss set up a repo in our shared GitHub and I want to add a description, but there is no edit button to do so:

[image: Description missing]

I am the only contributor so I want to add one to make it easier to find. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no "Edit" button or "Settings" tab visible in the screenshot, it means you're not an administrator of the repository.

You'll have to ask your boss to promote you to Admin status on the repository, or ask them to set these up for you.

Comment: That worked. Not being familiar with GitHub, I thought this is what it might be, but wanted to make sure (and there wasn't much online help to point this out)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**click on the about setting icon** --> a popup opens where you can enter your description